# URL Rewrite Is Affecting CKFinder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, ckfinder

On my htaccess I have the below code in it

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo/ 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+?)\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]
```

This code affects `CKFinder` making it output `Folder not found. Please refresh and try again`.

The third line `RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]` if commented, CKFinder starts working well.

Please can anyone help point me in the right direction of how to fix this issue?